# Photoswipe gallery with array of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, photoswipe

So i chose to use Photoswipe and arranged my markup included the css and min.js into my html file as it says so in photoswipe documentation. I've arranged my photos and markup as it is shown in the codepen example:

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                 <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
                    <a href="images/1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
                       <img src="images/1.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
                    </a>
                    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Sunset</figcaption>           
                 </figure>
              </div>
              .
              .
              .
              and so on
```

I've added the photoswipe html par just before the closing body tag and i've included the script shown in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9wea0gy4/

When i click on my image i end up with this kind of error

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/Kora%C4%8D/Desktop/Projekti/MMS/Portfolio/index.html#section3&gid=null&pid=1' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Anyone has a clue what's this about?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue and it looks like this error is happening when you test locally. I uploaded my files to my webserver and the issue resolves itself. It looks like it's a problem with parsing the URL somewhere in the Photoswipe code:

https://github.com/angular/router/issues/326

Comment: Nice to hear that, i don't know if running it trough wamp helps but i'll try. Will leave feedback